# Не отображается редактор темы на wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Два дня бьюсь над проблемой. Хотел отредактировать текст в теме на главной странице.
Отображается следующее
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Ничего не работает. Подскажите в чем может быть проблема? Может быть кто-то сталкивался. Я новичок - поэтому вопрос может быть элементарным. Но путем поиска решения в гугле я ничего подобного не нашел

Comment: Причин может быть множетсво и сказать что-то конкретное по скриншоту будет довольно сложно.

Comment: В логах ищи ответ.